# Creating Archive build in ios (Xcode 4.3)

Tags: xcode, build, archive

I'm having trouble creating an archive build in xcode 4.3.

The "AppName.app" file is RED even though I've set the release configuration to the correct profile, and selected "Build For Archive"

Addition: This is what i see in the xcode window when I click the "AppName.app" in the left hand column:

[image]

I also see the same image in the finder window, I've zipped up this file and sent it as the application binary.

I hope this isn't a problem?

Thanks,
Uba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you select "IOS Device" and after, you select "Archive", at the end of the build XCode open automaticaly the "Organizer" and you can see the archive package

Comment: Hi Alessio, thanks for the reply, where do I select "IOS Device" do you mean the upper left corner where it could either be IOS device, Iphone Simulator, or Ipad Simulator?, if so, I do but I do not see the archive appear in the organizer window

Comment: your build failed?  if you open manually "Windows -> Organizer" and after you select the archive tab, you the list of archive build?

Comment: The build actually succeeded, but nothing shows up in the organizer. and the AppName.app remains RED. I did a "clean" build prior, maybe I need to do a run build before doing a archive build?

Comment: Ok, I made some progress, but when I click on the appName.app icon, I get a target picture with a "do not use" superimposed on it (like a circle, with a line through it) is that a problem?

Comment: No,it's not necessary. is correctly that the AppName.app remains RED, because only after a Run, you can try the .app file

Comment: you have try to open manually the "Organizer" and check the "Archive" tab?

Comment: I tried, nothing shows up, although I was able to create a .app file and zipd it up and submitted it through Application Loader. Lets see what happens